# xen VM boot logs - how to locate

Tags: xen

Working with a VM that starts to boot and then promptly shuts down. Hoping to locate VM boot logs on Xen host but not sure where to look. Examining /var/log/* doesn't show anything obvious.

Suggestions?

Comment: What kind of Xen install? If you have `xen-hypervisor` installed on Debian or Ubuntu, `/var/log/xen` will show the per-machine logs.

Comment: Xen 7.x. The 'hypervisor.log' file in `/var/log/xen` hasn't been written to since 5/19 of this year despite this host (as part of a cluster) being in constant use.

Comment: Do you have Xen-server? Or Ubuntu? Or Debian? xl toolstack? We need more details. Looking at your version number, you have Xen Server?

Comment: Xen server. Yes.